# Yui_compressor not working in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, minify, assetic, yui-compressor

I used [this guide](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/less-css-with-assetic-and-symfony-2) to adding the yui_compressor to my symfony project. But its not creating the minified files. Below are the settings I applied, please take a look and tell me what might be going wrong. 
Config File

```
// Added this to the config.yml file in app/config (and yes, I'm on a mac)  
    yui_css:
        jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/filter/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        java: /usr/bin/java
```

Base Twig

```
// Added this to the :base.html.twig in app/Resources/views

    {% stylesheets  filter='yui_css' output='public/css/compiled-main.css'
        'public/css/main.css'
    %}
```

Added the file in the [yui_compressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/downloads) zip file under build to the app/Resources/filter/java folder in my symfony project

Comment: Can you post the full `{% stylesheets %}` code?

Comment: Have you tried dumping the asset files using `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod`? See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1 - Download and add yuicompressor to your project**

Unzip, go to build/ dir and extract yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar to put it in your app/Resources/java/ project dir. (In addition, you can rename yui file for yuicompressor.jar)

**2 - Enable yui compression for prod environement**

This is logical to add yui compressor in your config_prod.yml file and not for all environment (you should remove lines from config.yml).

So add theses lines in config_prod.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug: false
    filters:
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
            apply_to: "\.js"
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
            apply_to: "\.css"
```

**3 - Verify you prod controller file**

Go to web/app.php, and set prod / false (false for no debug).

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

**4 - Clear cache**

If you want to rebuild your CSS and JS (after update), never forget to clear cache in prod otherwise modifications will be ignored by yui compressor:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

**5 - Regenerate fixtures with compression**

Finally, you can generate and compress your files !

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug -v
```

Note that -v show more details about the process of compression, you will be able to see if there is an error taht causes problems with yui compressor !

For example, the JS comment tag "/!" causes trouble with yui compressor, you should rename all "/!" for "/*" in your JS files.

That's it ^^

Comment: Please note that YUI compressor is now abandoned (and not maintained) and that people should use another solution like UglyfyJS and CSS, as explained here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html

Comment: Sybio is correct the same config will not get picked up from config.yml but it must be from config_prod.yml. Also make sure you have java installed on your server (checking with java -version from command line to see if it existing) Thanks Sybio.